# How to check if a string contains a specific character

Tags: regex, string, bash, contains

I've been trying to make a condition in a bash script which will tell me if the given string contains chars other than letters or a hyphen.

i.e, this is a legal string: `hello-world`

and that one is not: `hello-123-there`

This is what I have tried so far but I think I also have a logic mistake:

```
if ! [[ "$1" == *-* ]] && ! [[ "$1" =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+$ ]] ; then
        echo "the line is bad"
        exit
fi
```

(while $1 refers to the string, of course).
Would love to get some help from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex features of BASH:

```
[[ "$str" =~ ^[a-zA-Z-]*$ ]] && echo "valid" || echo "invalid"
```

OR using glob:

```
[[ "$str" == *[^-[:alpha:]]* ]] && echo "invalid" || echo "valid"
```

Which is same as:

```
if [[ "$str" =~ ^[a-zA-Z-]*$ ]]; then
    echo "valid"
else
    echo "invalid"
fi
```

Comment: thanks, but - i dont understand the "&&" and "||" usgae, can you plz write the condition? thanks.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Plain glob patterns work too: `[[ $str == *[^-[:alpha:]]* ]] && echo invalid`

Comment: That's correct @glennjackman. Thanks editing the answer with this option as well.